# RadUpload in FormView in RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, telerik, formview, radupload

I have a `RadUpload` in the edit template of a `FormView`. My desired behavior is

- `Formview` should open in `ReadOnly` Mode
- On clicking the update button, a postback should occur

So the desired transition scheme is `ReadOnly->Edit` should be `Ajaxified Edit->Readonly` should be a postback.

I have tried using [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/radupload-inside-ajaxified-formview.aspx) post, but I cannot access the update button in my script (as the formview opens in readonly mode).

Any idea how can I get my desired functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload_uploadingajax.html) online help article which shows how to upload files when RadUpload is inside RadAjaxPanel.